# Hiding the Set accessor

Tags: c#

I have a base class, FooBase. On it are a few standard read/write properties. When i subclass this, i want the subclass to have only read properties. Is this possible?

```
class FooBase
{
    public virtual int ID{get; set;}
    public virtual string Name{get;set;}
}

class Foo : FooBase
{
   public override int ID {get;}
   public override string Name{get;}
}
```

I know that code doesnt work, but it might give you some idea what im after

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have your class heirarchy the wrong way round.

The writable version should be a subclass of the readonly version. Here's one way you could do it:

```
class FooBase
{
    public int ID { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

class Foo : FooBase
{
    public void SetId(int id) { /* ... */ }
    public void SetString(string name) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of how i could do that? im having a massively blonde day today...

Answer (score 2):

You can't just remove a public member like that, or it will break anything that tries to treat a Foo object like a FooBase object.

You could try something like this:

```
public virtual string Name{get; protected set;}
```

Making the setter only available to classes derived from FooBase.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to provide answer to your question.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/768dc05e-db95-479d-b0a2-4fe478a47591